# How to do ALTER EXTENSION with Heroku's Postgres DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, schema, hstore

I'm using the `apartment` gem for my SaaS (built with Ruby on Rails) and one of its requirements is we need to install the `hstore` PostgreSQL extension via a dedicated schema (ie: `shared_extensions`), not the default `public` schema.

Heroku enables `hstore` by default; however it is installed in the `public` schema. When I tried to do:

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("ALTER EXTENSION hstore SET SCHEMA hstore;")`

the console returned:

`(3.6ms)  ALTER EXTENSION hstore SET SCHEMA hstore;
PG::Error: ERROR:  must be owner of extension hstore`

Currently it's impossible on the code side to make do with `hstore` extension being installed on `public`, so I definitely have to find a way to put `hstore` extension on `shared_extensions` schema.

Will there be a way to do this on Heroku? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I can't do `ALTER EXTENSION hstore SET SCHEMA hstore;` on Heroku. I've documented the workaround [here](https://github.com/influitive/apartment/pull/158)

1. Append `?schema_search_path=public,hstore` to your `DATABASE_URL` environment variable, by this you don't have to revise the `database.yml` file (which is impossible since Heroku regenerates a completely different and immutable `database.yml` of its own on each deploy)
2. Run `heroku pg:psql` from your command line
3. And then `DROP EXTENSION hstore;` (**Note:** This will drop all columns that use `hstore` type, so proceed with caution; only do this with a fresh PostgreSQL instance)
4. Next: `CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS hstore;`
5. Finally: `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore SCHEMA hstore;` and hit enter (`\q` to exit)

Answer (score 4):

A less destructive alternative work around:

1.) Put your application in maintenance mode: 

`heroku maintenance:on -a [app-name]`

2.) Backup up your database: ALWAYS BACK IT UP :)

`heroku pg:backups capture -a [app-name]`

3.) Copy your database locally: 

`heroku pg:pull [Database URL] mylocaldb -a [app-name]`

4.) Now you have the db locally, you can move the extensions without any destruction of data or columns because you have local superuser priv.:

`ALTER EXTENSION "hstore" SET SCHEMA hstore;`

5.) Now export this version back to production:

`heroku pg:push mylocaldb [Database URL] -a [app-name]`

6.) Take your app out of maint. mode and you now have the extensions installed in the shared schema of hstore.

7.) You will still need to perform step 1 of Tu H.'s response if you are on rails < 4.1

OR if you are running rails 4.1+ you can just update your database.yml file:

`schema_search_path: "public,hstore"`

This is a less destructive way to get what you want done without too much downtime.